# Extra blank page while designing front cover with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, blank-page, front-matter, covers

I’m trying to design the front cover of a book with `tikz` package. The following is my latex code:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=white,line width=.1em,font=\fontsize{90}{90}\selectfont]
\filldraw[color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\draw (.05\paperwidth,0) -- (.05\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\draw (0,.1\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.1\paperheight);
\draw (0,.3\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.3\paperheight);
\draw (0,.5\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.5\paperheight);
\draw (0,.7\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.7\paperheight);
\draw (0,.9\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.9\paperheight);
\node[draw,align=center] at (.8\paperwidth,.5\paperheight) {B\\O\\O\\K};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But after compiling the latex code, except the front cover, I get a extra blank page before it. What is the problem with it?

Comment: Have you tried setting geometry in the preamble rather than starting a new geometry as soon as you start the document?

Comment: It thinks the picture is too big but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rectangle larger than the paper by `\pgflinewidth` since the upper point for rectangle is at  `(\paperwidth,\paperheight)`. You can either

1. use `fill` instead of `filldraw` → `\fill[color=blue,use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);`
2. or use `($(\paperwidth,\paperheight)+(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)$)` in the construction of rectangle. This needs `calc` library. → `\filldraw[color=blue,use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle ($(\paperwidth,\paperheight)+(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)$);`

Also note that I have used the big blue rectangle as the bounding box.

Full code

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=white,line width=.1em,font=\fontsize{90}{90}\selectfont]
\fill[color=blue,use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
%%\filldraw[color=blue,use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle ($(\paperwidth,\paperheight)+(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)$);
\draw (.05\paperwidth,0) -- (.05\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\draw (0,.1\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.1\paperheight);
\draw (0,.3\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.3\paperheight);
\draw (0,.5\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.5\paperheight);
\draw (0,.7\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.7\paperheight);
\draw (0,.9\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,.9\paperheight);
\node[draw,align=center] at (.8\paperwidth,.5\paperheight) {B\\O\\O\\K};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A short version:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=white,line width=.1em,font=\fontsize{90}{90}\selectfont]
\filldraw[color=blue,use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle ($(\paperwidth,\paperheight)+(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)$);

\foreach \x in {0.1,0.3,...,0.9}{
   \draw (0,\x\paperheight) -- (.05\paperwidth,\x\paperheight);
}
\draw (.05\paperwidth,0) -- (.05\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\node[draw,align=center] at (.8\paperwidth,.5\paperheight) {B\\O\\O\\K};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use `calc` library, just use

```
(\paperwidth-\pgflinewidth,\paperheight-\pgflinewidth)
```

as noted by  Torbjørn T.

Comment: You can do just `(\paperwidth-\pgflinewidth,\paperheight-\pgflinewidth)`, no need for `calc`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Good point. Some how, I am biased towards using `calc`. However, I have added a note in the answer. Thanks for the ping. :)